# minus one total from another PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to work out a members balance, this is the total amount for products minus the total number for payments.

Below is my code;

```
$prod_total = $qry->fetchColumn();
$payments_total = $row['sum'];
$balance = floatval($prod_total) - floatval($payments_total);
echo" $balance;"
```

Example, products total is `100.00` - payments are `50.00` and `20.00`
and the `$balance` is showing as `-70.00`

However this just shows the total for payments as a minus?!?
Thanks

Comment: @JohnConde I have tried the below but this isnt working? `$balance = $qry->fetchColumn();-$row['sum'];  echo" $balance";`

Comment: Get rid if the semi-colon before the subtraction operator.

Comment: Men, you really need to learn PHP syntax FIRST, then start coding.

Comment: @user3453019 - you're going to have to give a lot more information. For one thing, I'm assuming `$row['sum']` is being set in a loop, because your example has two numbers. You didn't mention that in your question. Can you edit your question, and give more of the code? What, exactly, are you trying to do - do you just want to print out the balance? Or do you want to change it in the database? In which case, can you include the details of how you're getting the information from the database in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing the math with floatval()
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

```
$prod_total = $qry->fetchColumn();
$payments_total = $row['sum'];
$balance = floatval($prod_total) - floatval($payments_total);
echo $balance;
```

Comment: This just shows the total payments as a minus? prod total is 150.00 payments are 50.00 and 20.00 balance is showing as -70.00